# having issues with htaccess in codeigniter Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, codeigniter

My front end is in angular. I am using HTML5 mode routing in angular. I have configured my htaccess file for redirecting any URL to index.php, But it seems that it is not working.

Below is my htaccess code :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php/#/$1 [L]
</ifModule>
```

Please help.

Comment: On server side using `#` doesn't make much sense since that is processed on client side only.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/#/$1 [L]
```

By this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/#/$1 [L]
```